# In Android MapView canvas, how do I draw circles with non-interacting alpha?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-canvas

I am having an issue much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196864/on-an-android-canvas-how-do-i-draw-overlapping-shapes-with-non-interacting-alph), but here are more specifics as to my problem.

I'm writing an application using MapView and I'm painting an icon at the current location on the map. I also want to draw a semi-transparent circle around the current location to indicate accuracy of the location. While the "current location" icon moves around I want all accuracy ranges to remain on the screen.

If I use `canvas.drawCircle(...)` at every location update a new circle is drawn indicating accuracy. The issue is if any part of the circles overlap the alphas eventually end up overlapping and getting darker.

I've also tried the following:

```
Path accuracyPath;
accuracyPath.addCircle(...);
Paint pathPaint = new Paint();
pathPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
pathPaint.setAlpha(15);
canvas.drawPath(accuracyPath, pathPaint);
```

This prevents the overlapping alpha issue, but if I move the map around the Path just gets painted all over the place.

I haven't yet found a satisfactory answer to solve this problem.

Please help!

Comment: This post has some useful hints.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065597/draw-circle-with-transparency-in-mapview